# Hibernate - group by a column, collect to list and limit

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In my application I have a table `customer_facts` represented by the hibernate entity:

```
@Entity
data class PersistedCustomerFacts(
    @Id
    val id: Long,
    val customerId: String
    val factValue: String
)
```

It keeps all customers' facts. Each customer may have multiple facts. I want to query the table and get a result consisting of a list of each customerId with its facts. But I also want it to be pageable by the customerId so for example I can fetch only first two customers. I would like to show an example. Let's say \I want to get first two results ordering by the customerId

The data in the database:

```
id, customerId, factValue
1, 'customerA', 'likes cats'
2, 'customerA', 'likes dogs'
3, 'customerA', 'doesnt likes rats'
4, 'customerB', 'likes cats'
5, 'customerB', 'likes rats'
6, 'customerB', 'likes bikes'
7, 'customerB', 'doesnt likes cats'
8, 'customerC', 'doesnt likes bikes'
```

the final output would be

```
[
    {
        "customerId": "customerA",
        "facts": ["likes cats", "likes dogs", "doesnt likes rats"]
    },
    {
        "customerId": "customerB",
        "facts": ["likes cats", "likes rats", "likes bats"]
    },
]
```

I hope it's clear now 
I've got a problem to do it, especially with how to make the result be pageable by the customerId field. I tried something like this:

```
        val criteriaBuilder = entityManager.criteriaBuilder
        val criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(PersistedCustomerFacts::class.java)
        val customerFacts = criteriaQuery.from(PersistedCustomerFacts::class.java)
        criteriaQuery
            .select(customerFacts)
            .orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(customerFacts.get("customerId")));
        val typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery)
        typedQuery.firstResult = 0
        typedQuery.maxResults = 2
        return typedQuery.resultList
```

However it's bad because I limit the rows so I might not fetch all of the facts of some customerId. How to solve such problem ? Maybe I should do two queries ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for the [rich pagination API](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/core/manual/en_US/index.html#pagination) provided by Blaze-Persistence which is a library that works on top of JPA!

There are multiple ways you can do this, but for simplicity I assume that you have an inverse assocation `@OneToMany @JoinColumn(name = "customerId") Set<PersistedCustomerFacts> facts` mapped in your `Customer` entity.

With the pagination API you could write a query like the following

```
CriteriaBuilder<Customer> cb = criteriaBuilderFactory.create(entityManager, Customer.class);
cb.fetch("facts");
PaginatedCriteriaBuilder<Customer> pcb = cb.page(0, 2);
return pcb.getResultList();
```

If you don't have that inverse assocation you could use a string aggregation function

```
CriteriaBuilder<Tuple> cb = criteriaBuilderFactory.create(entityManager, Tuple.class);
cb.from(PersistedCustomerFacts.class, "fact");
cb.select("fact.customerId");
cb.select("GROUP_CONCAT(fact.factValue, 'SEPARATOR', ';')");
cb.groupBy("fact.customerId");
PaginatedCriteriaBuilder<Tuple> pcb = cb.page(0, 2);
return pcb.getResultList();
```

and then split the string to a collection.

If you have logic written with the JPA Criteria API that you want to reuse, you can use the jpa-criteria module which is an implementation of the JPA Criteria API that generates a Blaze-Persistence `CriteriaBuilder`.